# Clojure lein-environ plugin classpath error

Tags: intellij-idea, clojure

I am using  InteliJ IDEA to develop my application which was working as expected until I added the `[lein-environ "1.0.1"]` plugin to my `project.clj`.

If I run my application using `lein` it all runs as expected however, if I launch a debug repl (need to test the logic etc) then I get the following error:

```
Could not locate lein_environ/plugin__init.class or lein_environ/plugin.clj on classpath. Please check that namespaces with dashes use underscores in the Clojure file name.
```

My 'project.clj' contents:

```
defproject some-project "1.0.0"
  :description "Some random description"
  :license {:name "FILLER DATA"}
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.7.0"]
                 [environ "1.0.1"]
                 [stencil "0.5.0"]
                 [clj-http "2.0.0"]
                 [clj-ssh "0.5.11"]
                 [cheshire "5.5.0"]
                 [clj-time "0.11.0"]
                 [amazonica "0.3.33"]
                 [expectations "2.0.9"]
                 [im.chit/cronj "1.4.1"]
                 [dk.ative/docjure "1.9.0"]
                 [com.draines/postal "1.11.3"]
                 [org.clojure/data.csv "0.1.3"]
                 [org.clojure/java.jdbc "0.4.1"]
                 [...]]
:plugins [[lein-environ "1.0.1"]
         [lein-expectations "0.0.8"]]
  :resource-paths ["resources" "jobs"]
  :profiles {:repl {:env {:in-repl? true}}}
  :main source-file.core)
```

If I remove the `[lein-environ "1.0.1"]` from the plugins the debug repl launches and functions as expected however, I need the plugin to be able to generate the `.lein-env` from my `profiles.clj`

Any idea what is causing this issue? I have tried removing environ from `~/.m2/path/to/lein-environ` but no luck.

Comment: Do you start REPL from within InteliJ IDEA or from the command line?

Comment: @Timur right click on `project.clj` launch debugging repl for... from inside the IDE

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a bug in a recent version of Cursive. If you upgrade it should be fixed.